# Integrate google search

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, google-search-api

I am trying to integrate google search results with my rails application but unable to get proper response. I am following this link

```
https://github.com/wiseleyb/google_custom_search_api
```

Here is my code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def index
      results = GoogleCustomSearchApi.search("restaurant near sector 2 noida")

        results["items"].each do |item|
            puts item["title"], item["link"]
        end
  end
end
```

The response which I am getting is this

```
Youth Thrash Restaurant Owner In Noida | Full Video - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PSKUacsmnY
Karim's Hotel Restaurant - Delhi - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKqOlthRO2w
Bikanervala Bliss Fine Dine Restaurant at Noida Sec-18 - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9J4R-sC3-w
Top 5 | Fine Dining Restaurants In Noida - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLXno_bYhRY
Dev's Bar & Restaurant, Sector-62, Noida - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KZ2pz_azFA
Noida Kids- Sector 38 McDonalds - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-JCZF1FkCc
Review of Theos, Noida | Bakery & Cake Shops Restaurants- Italian ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1LFabXPeks
Bistro 37, Noida | Coffee Shops/Cafes /Restaurants- Continental ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pVstxQ0EvQ
Review of Desi Vibes, Noida | Restaurants- North Indian ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRwJPuv8vC4
sector 62 noida
https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1Y_e1x5df5tCuGjKOCRzx3bXBv9w&hl=en
```

Which is giving me wrong result .So there any way i can integrate google search which can give me proper answers

I should get these results as showing in google [image: google results]

Comment: What result do you expect? It seems to me that the results are just fine.

Comment: No results are not fine it is showing me wrong result let me update the question and show you what actually  google is giving

Comment: I have updated my questions .I have shown what google is giving.I need those results but unable to do .

Comment: So you want to display places? If yes, try [Google places](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and [google places wrapper](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places)